# Flushend creating black lines at end of document

Tags: vertical-alignment

I am using the `flushend` package in TeXmaker on my Mac in order to balance the lines at the end of my two column paper.  However, the PDF is always created with horizontal black lines near the end of the document that are in the area of the text.  I'm wondering what I need to do to fix this.

Comment: Can we see some form of code that replicates the current behaviour you're experiencing?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean this rule:

[image]

In which case simply comment out `\showcolsendrule`

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{flushend}
\showcolsendrule
\def\a{\stepcounter{enumi}\Roman{enumi} one two three four five }
\def\b{\a\a Blue black red\a\a\a\a}
\def\c{\a\a\a\b\par\b\b\b\b\a\a\a\b\a\a\a}


\begin{document}

\c
\end{document}
```